# React Native + Android native module: HMRClient is not a registered callable module

Tags: android, react-native

I'm developing a native module for ReactNative. Right now I'm toying with the native code part.
I have created the module with create-react-native-module script. I'm *systematically* getting the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: Module HMRClient is not a registered callable module (calling setup)
```

I have pinned down the problem to when I reference NativeModules inside the index.js for my module:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
//const <...my module name...> = NativeModules.<...my module name...>;  // <---- NOT WORKING

class <...some js class...> {
    constructor() {
        const <...my module name...> = NativeModules.<...my module name...>;  // <-- WORKING
        <...my module name...>.debugMessage("Salve mondo advertising");
    }
}
```

Maybe some weird race condition on library loading?

The common workarounds for this HMRClient error (disabling Fast Refresh on the app, cleaning the gradlie build and/or the node_modules, etc.) do not seem to work.

Here is my `react-native info` output:

```
System:
    OS: Linux 4.15 Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4810MQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
    Memory: 947.73 MB / 15.60 GB
    Shell: 4.4.20 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 11.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.8.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 25, 28
      Build Tools: 25.0.2, 28.0.3, 29.0.0, 29.0.3
      System Images: android-19 | Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
  npmPackages:
    react: ^16.9.0 => 16.13.1 
    react-native: ^0.61.5 => 0.61.5 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.

As I understand, your module didn't published on npm and didn't imported from `node_modules`.

It may happen when you place `index.js` file of your module outside of react-native project, in which it used. It causes double import of react-native. So `registerCallableModule('HMRClient')` calls twice. So it causes this error

Try to replace `index.js` file of your native module to your react-native project. It works for me